# Two Javascript and CSS files as build output in Nuxt3

Tags: webpack, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm working in Nuxt3 and I've got part of the code which will be working as a separate module that users can use via iframe.

I would like to keep my Nuxt3 project and iframe module separate, so two Javascript files and two CSS files, but both have to live in the same Nuxt3 project because they are both connected via settings/preview pages.

Anyone has any experience with such setup? Or should I put these two in separate projects or maybe install something like Vite in the same project and build separate files via Vite and Nuxt3?

So far I tried to setup Nuxt3 config via `css` setting https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#css but it's still combining files. I also tried adding Vite and building separate process for module's output but I failed on setting up paths.

Comment: Not really familiar with Nuxt but vite can split modules into chunks using glob import during build: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Comment: Thank @DaleRyan! I'm using Vite on its own in different project and I've got two files output there, but here, with Nuxt, it's a different story and I can't figure it out.